# Asynchronous forEach for image convert base64 promise.all

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, promise

I am using React. I want to use the `Promise.all` . But I couldn't figure out how to use it. I have a `imageUrls` array ı have to convert them `base64Format`, when ı did this manually its okay but how can I use with `forEach`? Or any other solution for this?

Manual version

```js
const promise1 = new Promise ((resolve) =>{
     setTimeout(resolve,1000, 'test');
 )}
const promise2 = this.getBase64ImageFromURL("example image url");
const promise3 = this.getBase64ImageFromURL("example image url 2");

Promise.all([promise1,promise2,promise3]).then((res)=>{
   console.log(res)
 )}
```

I have a Url array and ı have to convert to base64 but `forEach` doesn't wait how can I implement structure?

```js
const imageUrls = ["exampleimageurl1", "exampleimageurl2", "exampleimageurl3"];

imageUrls.forEach((url)=> {
  this.getBase64ImageFromURL(url);
 )}
```

```js
getBase64ImageFromURL(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var convertedImage = new Image();
      convertedImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
      convertedImage.onload = () => {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = convertedImage.width;
        canvas.height = convertedImage.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(convertedImage, 0, 0);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        resolve(dataURL);
      };
      convertedImage.onerror = error => {
        reject(error);
      };
      convertedImage.src = url;
    });
  }
```

Comment: `forEach doesn't wait`, well, in all fairness, there is no mechanism and no attempt whatsoever inside the `forEach` to wait for the promise to resolve. No `.then()`, no `await`, so anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Correct, `forEach` knows nothing about promises and won't wait for anything to settle.

You probably want to use `map` with `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(imageUrls.map((url) => this.getBase64ImageFromURL(url)))
.then(results => {
    // ...use `results` array here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error here...
});
```

Comment: This is works thank youuu